# Transformation of dictionary to numpy array generates incorrect values within loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, while-loop, generator

I need to transform dicts from a generator object to a numpy array within a loop.

But all approaches known to me lead to identically incorrect values. Here's my recent code at the crucial point:

```
    ...
    i = 0 
    while time.time() < t+st: 
        genob = next(gen) 
        
        keys = np.fromiter(genob.keys(), dtype=int)
        vals = np.fromiter(genob.values(), dtype=int)

        if i == 0:
            mytest1 = genob
            mytest2 = keys
            mytest3 = vals
            i = 1  
        ...    
     ...
```

What I'm trying to do here is: get the dict generator object and get the values out for further usage. I get no errors, but the results are not as expected:

1. First lines of result mytest1 = genob:

   `mytest1: {0: 29, 1: 29, 2: 0, 3: 31, 4: 30, 5: 30, 6: 29, 7: 29, 8: 29, 9: 0, 10: 29, ...}`
2. First lines of result mytest2 = keys:

   `mytest2: array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11, ...])`
3. First lines of result mytest3 = vals:

   `mytest3: array([  31,    0,   30,   30,   29,   28,   30,   29,    0,   29,   0, ...])`

--> Keys are in correct order, but I do not receive correct key-value pairs. Why np.fromiter does not give me the correct values? If I use a transformation via dict.items and list or list comprehension or ... I get the identical incorrect result.

Now, magically, if I use

```
np.fromiter(mytest1.values(), dtype = int)
```

outside of my loop, the expected result is calculated:

```
array([  29,   29,    0,   31,   30,   30,   29,   29,   29,    0,   29, ...])
```

Unfortunately, this does only happen outside the loop - within the loop it does not help to transform via mytest1...

Kernel and / or windows restart do not change a thing.
Using float datatypes does not change a thing.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be?

Thanks for any help!

System information:

- system='Windows', release='10', version='10.0.19041', machine='AMD64', processor='Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel'
- Python 3.8.8 via conda 4.11.0 in ipynb; numpy 1.20.1

---

Additions:
Creation of Mini-Example: Works as expected - problem is only reproducable in full code.

Mini-Example:

```
import random
from statistics import mean
import numpy as np
import time

def MyGen(loop_time):
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() <= start_time + loop_time:
        v = 500
        n = 0
        #create empty dict
        mydict = {}   

        #create dict entries as lists
        for i in range(360):
            mydict.update({i:[]}) 

        #create entries for lists in correspondence to keys    
        mykeys = [random.randint(0,360-1) for i in range(v)]
        myvals = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(v)]

        #allocate values in dict
        for i in mykeys:
            mydict[i].append(myvals[n])
            n = n+1

        #calculate mean in dict
        for i in mydict.keys():
            if len(mydict[i]) > 0:
                mydict[i]=int(mean(mydict[i]))
            else:
                mydict[i]=0
        yield mydict

loop_time = 4 
start_time = time.time()
i = 0 
gen = MyGen(loop_time)
counter = 0
while time.time() <= start_time + loop_time:
    genob = next(gen)
    
    keys = np.fromiter(genob.keys(), dtype=int)
    vals = np.fromiter(genob.values(), dtype=int)

    if i == 0:
        mytest1 = genob
        mytest2 = keys
        mytest3 = vals
        i = 1    
    counter = counter + 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: You showed `mytest3`, but what about `mytest2`?  Do corresponding key/value pairs in `mytest2` and `mytest3` match those in the dictionary, despite being in a different order?  In other words, is each pair `(mytest2[k], mytest3[k])` an item in `genob.items()`?

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Warren, i just added result of mytest2 into the question. The key results are correct, but the key value pairs are not. I will try to build a reproducable example - I'll put that into the question as well. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I just do not get it - if I build a mini-example, everything works fine :-( So the problem is the generator object...? But that offers me a normal dict. No clue on how to proceed to find the reason for the depicted behaviour.